# Change event doesn't get called when the value of <select> is set programmatically

Tags: jquery

Normally, when a user selects an item in a `<select>`, the 'change' event gets fired.
However, when you change the value of the same `<select>` with `$('select').val('something')`, the event doesn't get fired.

I know I could do:
`$('select').val('something').trigger('change');`
but that's not the problem I'm trying to solve...

Is there a way to get the change event working, without manually triggering it?

I put together a quick JsFiddle to better explain the problem, check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/W723K/1/

Cheers

Comment: *"without manually triggering it"* ... no.

Comment: short answer: no, use trigger()

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  `.val()` will not do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, unless you manually trigger the change function. If you don't like typing that code several times, extend the jQuery object. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W723K/2/**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.changeVal = function(value){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).val(value).trigger('change');
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

//Usage:
$('select').changeVal('something');
```