# HTML: listen for *all* changes to an input, not just keyboard-driven changes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example, if I've got an input like this:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" />
```

How can I be notified when the value is changed programatically (for example, as a result of `$("#myInput").val("new value")`)?

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ax9y/

**Edit**: please note, the question is asking how to *listen for changes*, not “how to manually dispatch changes”. I'm well aware that I can manually dispatch change events, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905871/change-event-doesnt-get-called-when-the-value-of-select-is-set-programmatical/7905958#7905958

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: @MarcB That "duplicate" question is completely different. This question is asking for a value change, not for a DOM modification.

Comment: Modifying the value of an element is a DOM change.

Comment: @RobW again, that relies on “manually” triggering the change… Something I know that I can do, but I'd like to avoid, as it will lead to unhappy bugs.

Comment: @DavidWolever That's slightly different. It's a compact jQuery-plugin which combines `.val` and `.change`. If you want to detect changes, you have to either use a poller (!!!), or the method as suggested by MarcB.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `$` prototype to always trigger `change()` events whenever `val(value)` is called:

```
$.prototype.changeval = $.prototype.val;
$.prototype.val = function(v) {
    if (v) {
        $(this).changeval(v);
        $(this).change();
    } else {
        return $(this).changeval();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note: do *not* use this if you ever plan on calling val(value) in the change() handler for the object that was just changed. I.e.

`$("#foo").change(function(e) {
    $(this).val("bar");
});
`

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the change: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2ax9y/1/

---

A little differently: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2ax9y/2/

Comment: That's not idea for two reasons: first, it means adding a `.trigger('change')` to all my code which modifies form fields (lame?), and second my change handlers can't rely on having a “real” change `event`.

Comment: @DavidWolever see my second fiddle.

Comment: Uuhhh… Isn't that exactly the same, except with the manually dispatched `change` event being manually dispatched from somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidWolever see related Q's in the comments in the OP

Comment: @DavidWolever his second method requires it be written in only one place.  It basically ties `click` and `change` together

Comment: Sure, but what if the input is changed because of something *other* than a click? Obviously I could dispatch change events *everywhere* the element is changed… But that's pretty lame.

Comment: @DavidWolever that is the only way you can do it at the moment. you need to attach handlers everywhere you may need them..

Comment: @DavidWolever you can however bind multiple events with the same `bind` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably subscribe to *every* change on an input element, but you can check if there has been a change since you last checked and do that within some desired time granularity.

Make a checker function and loop it with your desired time granularity—100ms is a good start, adjust to your needs.

Hypothetical untested implementation:

```
var last_value = null;

function handle_changed() {
    // Do something here
}

function check_value() {
    var v = $("#myelement").val();
    if(v !== last_value) {
        last_value = v;
        handle_changed();
    }
}

setInterval(check_value, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an inherent ability of the change event.  You could manually trigger the change event when you programmatically change the value.

```
$("#myInput").val(+(new Date())).change();
```