# jQuery alert(event) does nothing when called by internal function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

This is really weird. When the clear function is called and resets the value, the Filter change function is then called. The WEIRD part is there is no event BUT any check I do on event like `event != NULL` or `event != 'undefined'` or `event != void 0` do not work! It blows past the check as if event does exist. If I try to alert the event... it works fine when there is a real click event but when it is called by clear it completely kills the function without doing the alert and without any errors!

```
$('.clear').live("click", function() {
   page.find('.Filter').val("");
});

$('.Filter').live("keyup change", function(event) {
if(event)
    alert(event);
else
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: When a value is updated by a script, the events are not automatically triggered. This question is a duplicate of [Change event doesn't get called when the value of <select> is set programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905871/change-event-doesnt-get-called-when-the-value-of-select-is-set-programmatical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events for filter are not being called when you click the button, the problem is your change event on filter, change fires when you leave focus of the input box.  If your typing in there and then go to click the clear button you're going to get an alert like clicking clear caused the event to be called but its really your `change` event being called by leaving focus of the input box, remove the change event.

Change your filter events to

`$('.Filter').live("keyup", function(event) {`

Comment: IF that were the case then the alert would work instead of crashing the function. IF I remove the alert(event) then the rest of the code executes... if I have alert(event) the function dies... but ONLY when clicking clear. So why would if(event) pass but alert(event) crash

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, no one here can replicate your problem...  having an event of `keyup` or `change` on an element doesn't get called if its value is cleared through another function with `.val("")`.  You'll have to provide more info for anyone else to help you further.  Cause I've tested in FF, Chrome and IE and there's no problem.  What version of jQuery are you using?  What browser is the problem in? and make a jsfiddle of your exact code duplicating the problem.  Also I don't know what `page` is in `page.find('.Filter').val("");` but use `$('.Filter').val("");`

Comment: Well... as you previously said... the change event could be getting called with the focus changes due to clicking clear... which would then make it have nothing to do with the clear function. But I'm still left with there being no event when the focus changes.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish then?  Your question is stating when you click the 'Clear' button that its raising an event on your input box `.filter` which everyone has said and proved its not.  Your code `$('.Filter').live("keyup change", function(event) {` raises an event when a key is released while the input has focus `keyup` or when you tab/click out of the input box `change`, what else are you trying to do?  If you want your clear button to raise the change even then you need to trigger it via `$('.Filter').val("").trigger("change");`.

Answer (score 0):

In your "clear" function add `.trigger('change')`:

```
 page.find('.Filter').val("").trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting value doesn't trigger the `change` event, you need to manually trigger it like so:

```
$('.clear').live("click", function() {
   page.find('.Filter').val("").trigger( "change" );
});

$('.Filter').live("keyup change", function(event) {
if(event)
    alert(event);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PrALa/

If you remove the `trigger`, the alert will not be shown because it's not triggered.