# Jquery .val() doesn't trigger live(change) event

Tags: events, jquery

I have a select list and an event like:

```
$("#type").live('change', function() {
...
}
```

At somewhere I do that:

```
$("#type").val('something');
```

However that line of code doesn't trigger change event. What should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change event doesn't get called when the value of <select> is set programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905871/change-event-doesnt-get-called-when-the-value-of-select-is-set-programmatical)

Comment: in jquery BEFORE 1.7 you should use .delegate().trigger() in 1.7 you should use .on().trigger();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger the change manually:

```
$("#type").val('something').trigger('change');
```

Reference:

- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#type").val('something').trigger('change');
```