# Change to an option in a select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

As the title says how can i change to an option with value xx in a select?

I can do `$('#qty').val(2);` that works, but I want it to trigger the change() function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc3ES/

So at the document ready it should also alert "Works!" since it just got changed.

How can i do this?

Comment: Could you please describe a scenario in which the value changes without user interactivity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change event doesn't get called when the value of <select> is set programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905871/change-event-doesnt-get-called-when-the-value-of-select-is-set-programmatical)

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
 $('#qty').val(2).trigger("change");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc3ES/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the `trigger` method after the call to `val`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#qty').val(2).trigger('change');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
 $('#qty').val(2).change();
```

Although, you might want to consider adding an extension to do it in one for you:

```
$.fn.valchange = function(x){
    this.val(x).change();
} 

$('#qty').valchange(2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kc3ES/2/