# How can I get notified when the timezone-picker value is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using [timezone-picker](https://github.com/kevalbhatt/timezone-picker) to pick my timezones, and so far it's working great.

However, the one problem is that I can't convince it to tell me when the value is changed by using one of the `quickLink` buttons.

You can try this by going to the [demo](http://kevalbhatt.github.io/timezone-picker/) and sticking this code in your console:

```
jQuery("#map select").on("change", function(){
    console.log(jQuery('#map').data('timezonePicker').getValue()[0]);
});
```

If you do that, you'll see that changing the value via dropdown works just fine, but if you use the buttons to the right of the dropdown, it won't fire the handler. I'm guessing that's because the code isn't [calling .trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7905958/344286) when it sets the value, and yeah I could probably modify the Javascript *myself* but that seems like the wrong thing to do... is there any other way to get notified when this value changes?

Comment: If the component isn't raising the event by calling trigger I can't imagine how you would ever get notified of it.  I would update the library and submit a pull request, that'll make your changes legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook to the `map:clicked` events (as defined diggin' in to the source code).

Check this code in the demo page:

```
jQuery("#map").on("map:clicked", function(){
    console.log(jQuery('#map').data('timezonePicker').getValue()[0]);
});
```

The only difference is that you need to hook it to the initialization element (`#map`). There is no trigger on the main `select` element. The defined binded event is `map:clicked`. It will execute each time you change the selected option, click on the map or select one of the quick links.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I needed!